# Playframework running but not able to be accessed on 127.0.0.1

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have downloaded playframework from its official website https://playframework.com/ and tried following:

1. activator new [appname](It has downloaded all the jar files and went through well)
2. on activator ui it says

Play server process ID is 4419
    [info] play - Application started (Prod)
    [info] play - Listening for HTTP on /127.0.0.1:8888
    [info] a.e.s.Slf4jLogger - Slf4jLogger started

but however I am not access it on 127.0.0.1:8888. please help.

Thank in adv.

Comment: have you tried localhost:8888 ?

Comment: What kind of *no access*? Connection refused or infinite page loading? I had experienced troubles with Activator - infinite page loading and using all CPU cores - and the issue was in hostname - I changed it from `Desktop` to `desktop.local` and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Play defaults to port 9000 - what you're seeing on port 8888 is activator.

Go to http://127.0.0.1:9000 - if it doesn't work, it's because you're not running your Play app.

Either...

Go the the `Run` view the activator app in your browser (http://127.0.0.1:8888) and cilck the `Run` button.  If you do this, you will see the following (or similar) in the browser:

```
Setting up Play fork run ... (use Ctrl+D to cancel)
--- (Running the application, auto-reloading is enabled) ---
p.c.s.NettyServer - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000
(Server started, use Ctrl+D to stop and go back to the console...)
```

Or, run activator in console mode (on the command line, go to your Play app directory and type `activator` without `ui`).  When it starts up, type `run`.  You will see the following (or similar):

```
--- (Running the application, auto-reloading is enabled) ---
[info] p.c.s.NettyServer - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000
(Server started, use Ctrl+D to stop and go back to the console...)
```

You can now go to http://127.0.0.1:9000 to see your app.